# how to download the canvas as png image format only not as binary file?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I have a math editor in which I am using a canvas to write equations or any mathematical formulations, I want to  save that canvas as image, i am able to save the image as binary file which i have to open every time by choosing window photo viewer, I want to save it as a image only.

Till now, to save the image i used the following code:

```
var data = canv.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
window.location.href = data;
```

its saving it in binary file.

Comment: Why are you replacing the `image/png`? Shouldn't this be your required output?

Comment: Your question does not make sense. What do you think "binary file" is and why you need one?

Comment: my file is being saved in a file forma which i cant use directly. if i'll not replace it the image will not save. I am sending u a link hope u will understand my question. may i am not clear with my written ques.

Comment: http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/canvas2image/

Comment: plz do check it may be then u will be able to better understand my problem

Comment: thanks all for help i m done with my work.. I'm posting my ans

Answer (score 0):

This will fix your problem:

```
window.location = canv.toDataURL("image/png");
```

`canv` being the Canvas object.
You don't need to replace `image/png` with `image/octet-stream`.

Comment: I tried it with a custom canvas object I made.
I created a canvas with a rectangle and I tried the code. Probably your problem is somewhere else.
In order to convert a canvas to a PNG file, you just need to use `toDataURL("image/png")` and in order to open the PNG file, you need to use `window.location` or `window.location.href`.

Answer (score 0):

```
       var dl = $doc.getElementById("preview");

            function dlCanvas() 
            {
                var divs=$doc.getElementById("yahoo");

                canv = divs.childNodes[0];

                   var dt = canv.toDataURL('image/png');
                   this.href = dt;
            };
            dl.addEventListener('click', dlCanvas, false);
```

preview is anchor tag id on html page.